# React Router- Cant render A compmnent

Tags: reactjs

Hey Guys fairly Simple Question,
i got this bit of code:

```
     <Switch>
    <Route component={TodoEdit}  path="/app/edit/:id " />
    <Route component={TodoDetails}  path="/app/:id " />
    <Route component={TodoApp}  exact path="/app" />
    <Route component={Home} exact path="/" />
  </Switch>
```

The Bottom 2 components works fine, i can switch between them etc, the upper 2 don't, the one with the parameters, when i enter the id to go into details it doesn't render for some reason,

the URL does change to the correct one.

any solutions?

Comment: I think you probably want to fix your `edit` path to `/app/:id/edit`. Otherwise, your details and edit paths overlap

Comment: doesnt help unfortunately

Comment: @Kontantin can't you get me a codesandbox? actually, it might be 10x better.

Comment: add exact to the 2 top components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your routes to match the more specific ones first and then the variable ones. Something like the following :

```
<Route component={Home} exact path="/" />
<Route component={TodoApp}  exact path="/app" />
<Route component={TodoEdit}  exact path="/app/edit/:id" />
<Route component={TodoDetails}  exact path="/app/:id" />
```

Comment: thanks mate that works! can u give a quick explanation as to why?

Comment: Basically the way the routing works is that it's going down the list to see which route it matches to switch to it. The first two routes are easy to match since they are static and won't change. The next two routes are variable so `/app/:id` can technically = `/app/edit` since `:id` can be anything. In order above when the router sees `/app/edit` it knows to continue matching path but if `/app/:id` was first it would stop matching and render component since it thinks `/edit` is the `/:id` part of url.